# System.Text.Json check if array is null

Tags: c#, json, .net-framework-version, system.text.json

I'm just new in using [Sytem.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1).

How I can check if the `subscriptions` array is empty or `null`?

JSON:

```json
{
    "user": {
        "id": "35812913u",
        "subscriptions": [] //check if null
    }
}
```

and this is what I want to check if it is null.

```cs
if (subscriptions != null) {
    
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). It's best Json converting libarary.

Comment: I already done using newtonsoft. That's why I wanna try system.text.json :)
I can confirm that text.json is faster than newtonsoft that's why I wanna learn more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should have some classes to deserialize your json into:

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string[] Subscriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

In my example I am reading the content from a file called `data.json` and pass it to the `JsonSerializer`, checking properties for null using the [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
    private static async Task ProcessFile()
    {
        var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "data.json");

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            var text = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(file);

            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(text, new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            });

            if (result?.User?.Subscriptions?.Length > 0)
            {
                // do something
            }
            else
            {
                // array is empty
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need to get the data from an API, you can use the extension methods over the `HttpClient`, but I would suggest to use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to create your client:

```
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var result = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>("https://some.api.com");

    if (result?.User?.Subscriptions?.Length > 0)
    {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // array is empty
    }
```

You can do it using `JsonDocument` too, by making use of `GetProperty()`, or even better, `TryGetProperty()` methods:

```
    private static async Task WithJsonDocument()
    {
        var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "data.json");

        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            var text = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(file);

            using var stream = new MemoryStream(text);
            using var document = await JsonDocument.ParseAsync(stream);

            var root = document.RootElement;
            var user = root.GetProperty("user");
            var subscriptions = user.GetProperty("subscriptions");
            var subs = new List<string>();

            if (subscriptions.GetArrayLength() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var sub in subscriptions.EnumerateArray())
                {
                    subs.Add(sub.GetString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might helpful to me in the future. But for now I'm using a Jsondocument. I don't like to use a property. because I only needed a few information.

Comment: I've added an example using JsonDocument too, but I think deserializing your Json file into custom objects is much cleaner.

Comment: Yeah it's much cleaner. I actually already know Deserializing . that's why I wanna try Jsondocument. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about IHttpClientFactory. 
I actually processing API only. I'm gonna try it